# protobuf oneof backwards compatibility

Tags: protocol-buffers

If I had some protobufs created with the following protobuf schema

```
message Foo {
    Bar1 bar_1 = 1;

    Bar2 bar_2 = 2;
}
```

but later on updated the protobuf schema to

```
message Foo {
  oneof foo {
    Bar1 bar_1 = 1;

    Bar2 bar_2 = 2;
  }
}
```

Will this second version be able to read the protos created with the first version?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can.

A `Foo` message created with the first version of the schema can contain both a `bar_1` and a `bar_2`.

Code generated from the second schema is expecting there to be only a `bar_1` or only a `bar_2`, so regardless of whatever markers GPB puts in its wireformat to denote a `oneof`, this code wouldn't end up having both bar_1 and bar_2 set if both were in the data (the last one of bar_1 and bar_2 in the data would be the one that wins - thank you James Roper).

With the right schema syntax version (v3 makes everything optional) a message created using code for the first schema that contains only a `bar_1` or `bar_2` (made possible by the fields being optional) will be parsable by code generated from the second schema. `oneof` doesn't appear in the GPB wireformat.

All in all, it's best to not make assumptions about wireformat compatibility between conflicting schemas. It'd be easy to write a small utility to read `Foo` messages created by the first schema, check to see if there are 2 fields pressent, and create fresh `Foo` messages under the 2nd schema if there are not (you may have to compile the schema with appropriately diverse namespaces configured). That way you can catch the exceptions (2 fields present), and be sure to have ended up with compatible wireformat data.

Comment: This is wrong. The decoding code would know exactly what to do with it, because the protobuf spec specifies exactly how code expecting a oneof should handle a scenario where multiple values for that oneof are set, that is: "If the parser encounters multiple members of the same oneof on the wire, only the last member seen is used in the parsed message." So, the two schemas are compatible, with the caveat that decoding using the second schema may lose one of the values. But in any situation where you added a oneof like this, you're probably already only expecting one of them anyway.

Comment: @JamesRoper, Interesting, ok, yes, it will do a defined thing if both bar_1 and bar_2 are in the data, but the object parsed from the data will not contain both a bar_1 and bar_2 (A. Fenzry doesn't say whether their data can have both present). On a general note, it seems like an odd design choice for a parser to silently consume data that is not matching the intent of the schema (even if it's compatible with it...). I mean, how are you supposed to know, if the parser isn't going to tell you?!

Comment: I think the design choice is consistent with the general design approach of Protobuf. Protobuf tries to avoid encoding schema constraints onto the wire as much as possible, in order to give developers the flexibility to evolve schemas in a way that makes business sense. This gives developers the power to be able to say "these fields are effectively a oneof, the code that produces them never sets more than one, so I'm going to evolve the schema to represent that". Which is actually a common schema evolution that I've seen in practice. So I think it's a very pragmatic design choice.

Comment: Likewise, you can change a field from being a single field to being a repeated field, and the actual wire encoding doesn't change, which enables changes that make business sense to be done in a carefully managed roll out.

Comment: @JamesRoper, understood, but they've gone about "interface agility" in a way that defeats the point of having a schema in the first place. Hidden behaviour in an interface implementation adds risk, even if that behaviour is defined in the manuals somewhere. It's easy to do extensibility, optionality in, say, ASN.1 and still have rigidity over whether data is compliant or not. I use such rigidity to safely enable through-project interface agility without the risk that the devs on one side of an interface can unknowingly make a wrong assumption of how the other side creates / interprets data.

Comment: There are many, many different reasons for using a schema. Defeating just one of those reasons does not defeat every reason.

Answer (score 0):

They are compatible, but with a caveat.

The wire format for each schema is identical. If you were to encode the first one with both `bar_1` and `bar_2` set, then, according to [the protobuf spec](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#oneof-features):

> If the parser encounters multiple members of the same oneof on the wire, only the last member seen is used in the parsed message.

So, whichever field appears last in the encoded message (which could be either field, protobuf fields are usually encoded in order, but don't have to be), will be the one that is decoded.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the second version of the protobuf schema should be able to read protobufs created with the first version. When you update a protobuf schema, the changes you make only affect how new protobufs are encoded and decoded. Protobufs that were created with the previous version of the schema will still be encoded and decoded using the old schema. This means that the second version of the schema should still be able to read protobufs created with the first version, even though the schema has changed.

However, it is worth noting that when you make changes to a protobuf schema, you should take care to ensure that the changes are backward-compatible. This means that the new schema should still be able to read protobufs created with the old schema, without losing any information. In the example you provided, the change from the first version of the schema to the second is backward-compatible, so the second version should be able to read protobufs created with the first version. However, if you made a change that was not backward-compatible, the second version of the schema would not be able to read protobufs created with the first version.

Comment: `Given("I have a protobuf created with the first version of the schema", () => {
  // Create a protobuf using the first version of the schema
  const protobuf = createProtobuf(firstSchema);
});
`